# Error in Div tag

Tags: html

```
<table style =" border-collapse :collapse ; width :100px ; height: 100px ; align:centre:">
        <tr style="height :100%">
        <td dir="ltr" style="width:100px; vertical-align :top">
        <div class="portletContainer" >
        <div style="width:464px;margin-top:-1px; margin-left:7px;">
                <table id="pendingActivity" style= "border-collapse ;collapse ; border-right:1px solid #ddd; border-left:1px solid #ddd; border-bottom:1px solid #ddd">
                <caption class="color4" style = "height:30;width:100%"><span></span>
                <div class="clearFix">
                        <div id="containerPaging">
                        <table style ="border-collapse:collapse;">
                        <tbody>
                        <tr><td class="btnViewAllResults" style="height:34px;">
                        <a href="javascript:ns_Z7_B8MG3OTV00OV80IFR4GPBO10G7_viewAll('true','routeToReportsPendingActivity')" class="button btnViewAllC2">
                        <span>View All</span>
                        <img src="./btn-viewall-c2.gif" title="View All" alt="View All"/>
                        </a>
                        </td></tr>
                        </table>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                </caption>
```

I am getting error in line :    the error is invalid location in div tag and div tag not ended properly. but i have ended the div tag.. can sombody tell why i m getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

As per the code you have posted, the outer most table and some div tags are not closed. The entire snippet should look like this.

```
<table style =" border-collapse :collapse ; width :100px ; height: 100px ; align:centre:">
            <tr style="height :100%">
                <td dir="ltr" style="width:100px; vertical-align :top">
                    <div class="portletContainer" >
                        <div style="width:464px;margin-top:-1px; margin-left:7px;">
                            <table id="pendingActivity" style= "border-collapse ;collapse ; border-right:1px solid #ddd; border-left:1px solid #ddd; border-bottom:1px solid #ddd">
                                <caption class="color4" style = "height:30;width:100%"><span></span>
                                    <div class="clearFix">
                                        <div id="containerPaging">
                                            <table style ="border-collapse:collapse;">
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr><td class="btnViewAllResults" style="height:34px;">
                                                            <a href="javascript:ns_Z7_B8MG3OTV00OV80IFR4GPBO10G7_viewAll('true','routeToReportsPendingActivity')" class="button btnViewAllC2">
                                                                <span>View All</span>
                                                                <img src="./btn-viewall-c2.gif" title="View All" alt="View All"/>
                                                            </a>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </caption>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```